# Academic pay post-doc in Germany (TVL13, 75%)

Tags: postdocs, salary

I am wondering if the salary of a postdoc in Germany is sufficient. I am applying to a position which offers TVL13, but is reduced to 75% of the hours. With the cost of living in Germany being significantly higher that in Brazil, where I am currently living, I would like to know your experiences with this type of budget. The position is in the state of NRW.
The position is at the institute/university where I did my undergrad and is thematically a nice continuation of my PhD research. I have put some effort into writing up a 12-page research proposal and am motivated to work on the topic. I am familiar with several of the staff and worked at one of the funders, plus it is close to my family home, which would be a plus.

Comment: Since this is about the cost of living, the city/university is quite important. Düsseldorf/Münster/Köln are quite different to, say, Bielefeld or the eastern Ruhrgebiet.

Comment: Almost anywhere in Germany, you will be able to live ok with the 13. Many thousands of Germans do so.

Comment: "The position is at the institute/university where I did my undergrad" surely you are in the best position to judge the cost of living for a student there!

Comment: Apart from the very important point mentioned by @DCTLib, this also depends on what precisely you need the money for: are you alone or do you have a partner? If you have a partner, do they have their own income or will they mainly depend on yours? Do you have kids who depend on your income? Without such info it's almost impossible to give useful advice.

Answer (score 2):

According to this [calculator](https://oeffentlicher-dienst.info/c/t/rechner/tv-l/west?id=tv-l&g=E_13&stkl=1&r=&kk=15.5&z=75&zkf=0&f=0&zulage=&zv=keine), 75 percent of TVL-13 in *Stufe* 1 is equivalent to a net salary of roughly €2100 (i.e. after taxes and contributions that buy you a pension and health insurance etc.), plus about €1500 once per year ("Weihnachtsgeld"), so €2100 + €1500/12 = **€ 2225**.

The average full-time gross salary in Germany [was €4100 in 2021](https://de.statista.com/themen/293/durchschnittseinkommen/#topicOverview). For a 75% part-time position this amounts to €3075. Using this tax [calculator](https://app.handelsblatt.com/brutto-netto-rechner/?mwl=ok), we get a net salary of **€2083**. Ignoring the rather large wage differential (more than 10%, I think) between East and West Germany, this means your net salary would clearly be above average per hour. (It might be just above average in West Germany only.)

Having said that, a lot depends on your tax deductibles (whether you have a family in particular) and *Stufe*. I've made conservative assumptions in that regard. Most likely, you will be assigned *Stufe* 2 or 3, resulting roughly in an additional €100 or €200.

For comparisons, the [average rent](https://www.immowelt.de/immobilienpreise/bl-nordrhein-westfalen/mietspiegel) in NRW in 2021 for a mid-sized (80m^2) appartement was €584 plus energy and extra charges.

Brief, your salary won't permit big luxuries, but you will be more than okay outside the pricier stretches of Düsseldorf.